# Combine Google Analytics with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, google-analytics, universal-analytics

How do I configure Google Universal Analytics with AngularJS and instantly see some test data from my local test environment?

The current code:

```
  <script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-X', { // I have my actual UA id here
      cookieDomain: 'none'
    });

  </script>
</head>
```

I also have this one:

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
    ga('set', 'page', $location.url());
});
```

In the Real-time section in Google Analytics Dashboard i see '0 active visitors'.

Comment: I think it doesn't work properly when running on localhost

Comment: as for production environment, you can use this module https://github.com/doodeec/dc-angular-analytics

Comment: It doesn't seem (from the code) that it works with Universal Analytics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set a page url but you don't seem to have a call to the [send](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/method-reference#send) function

```
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

"set" merely sets fields (you can do this via a configuration object as the third parameter to the send pageview, too), you need "send" to, well, send them.